# Inverse of percentage?

Tags: arithmetic

What is the best way to cacluate the inverse of a percentage?  For example:

```
100 * .85 = 85
85 * x = 100
x = 100 / 85
x = 1.17647
```

Also,

```
279 * .85 = 237.15
237.15 * x = 279
x = 279 / 237.15
x = 1.17647
```

For any percentile `y` (i.e. `.85`), how do I cacluate its inverse (i.e. `1.17647`)?  Is the best way to just choose arbitrary numbers (operands) as I've done above?  Or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply calculate its multiplicative inverse by definition: for a non-zero real number $y$, $$y^{-1} = \frac 1y.$$

E.g., set your initial value to 1:

```
1 * . 85 = .85
.85 * x = 1
x = 1 / .85
x = 1.17647
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was just overthinking (or perhaps underthinking) it.  But thanks, your answer makes sense.