# 1 minus percentage: What is this called?

Tags: terminology, percentages

I'm trying to convert a percentage:

The original percentage represents how **bad** the condition of a asset is (in other words, a high number is bad). I would like to convert the percentage to represent how **good** the condition of an asset is (in other words, a high number is good).

To do this, I can simply subtract the original percentage from 1 to get the desired percentage.

Example:

```
 1 - 0.25 = 0.75
```

My question is: **What is this called in mathematics?** As far as I can tell, this is not the same thing as [inverse percentage](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49331/inverse-of-percentage).

Comment: Thank you for the bounty, @Wilson :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's called the *complement* of the percentage. The term comes from probability.