# What is the equivalent of reciprocal but for the sum instead of the product?

Tags: probability, terminology

Reciprocal is defined as:

> Two expressions or functions so related to another that their product is unity

So if $$\alpha * \beta = 1$$

Then you can say $\beta$ is the reciprocal of $\alpha$ i.e. $\beta = \dfrac{1}{\alpha}$

If $$\alpha + \beta = 1$$

is it possible to say $\beta$ is the _ ? _ of $\alpha$ ?

* **Edit** *

This question is in the context of probabilities.  For example if $\alpha$ is the probability of event X occurring and $\beta$ is the probability of event X not occurring.

Comment: Note:  $0-\alpha=\beta$ means $\beta$ is the opposite of $\alpha$

Comment: The *opposite*.

Comment: We use $1$ in the **reciprocal** because $1$ is the multiplicative identity.  We should use $0$ in the **opposite** because $0$ is the additive identity.

Comment: Thanks @BrianTung this was in the context of probabilities.  I was wondering if there was a term for this relationship.  I'll update the question to include that.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2425698/1-minus-percentage-what-is-this-called

Comment: Thank you @BrianTung.  Perfect, it's called the `Complement`.  I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

"Negative of" or "additive inverse of", or "opposite of" as suggested in comments.

Comment: Right, I grew up calling it the “negative”, but then I’m even older than you.

Comment: I think "opposite" is used like this only in the early years of schooling.

Comment: @Lubin  Not by much, and less and less in proportional terms each year.

Comment: What about 'negation'?

Comment: @OscarCunningham You could, and be understood. I wouldn't - "negation" usually applies to logical propositions.